# Angular 2: Get query params when app bootstrapping (before redirect)

Tags: angular, typescript, query-string

Currently, I'm implementing an embed chat system which allows user to embed the client chat app to their website. The client chat app using angular 2 (version 4). There are 2 type of user, agent and client. Client will be identified using their credential and and website ID (which is created when agent register his website). Therefore, I need to pass the website ID into each request from client app. I plan to put this website ID into url as a query param. However I cannot get this value when app bootstrapping.

The URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000?site=123456
```

Here is the app routing, when initializing, the root path will be redirected based on the login state:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/chat',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

And in the app component, I tried catching the query param like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterState,
    RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app works!';

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        //
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(p => console.log(p)); // result empty

        console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams); // result empty
    }
}
```

Assume that user already logged in, the app will redirect to http://localhost:3000/chat and the queryParams I try to catch return empty (in ngOnInit method), the query param in url also gone like http://localhost:3000/chat. If I place the query params after slug /chat (example http://localhost:3000/chat?site=123456) I can catch the value and the query param remains in url. I'm suspecting the redirect causing this, can anyone point out where I went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the router Module to use hash and it will work
in app.module
  replace RouterModule
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash:true}),

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guard to request a route before the router changes

The function canActivate can get
     activateRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
     state: RouterStateSnapshot
As parameters, the value of the query param is found in state.root.queryParams.site

Do not forget to return true value from the function